# .NET6 finalizer isn't called when project started from command line

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, .net-6.0, finalizer

I build .NET6 console project under release mode and when it's started from command line finalizer won't be called. While starting it from IDE calls the finalizer successfully.

.NET Framework 4.8 - calls finalizer from cmd and IDE 
.NET Core 3.1 - didn't call finalizer both from IDE and cmd

Does it meen that some settings to the project should be made? Or I just can't rely on finalizer even if **GC.Collect()** is force called?

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

            var gen = GC.GetGeneration(myClass);
            Console.WriteLine(gen);

            myClass = null;

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
 
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ctor");
        }

        ~ MyClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finalizer");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output when .exe started from command-line (both cmd and powershell):** 
Ctor
0

**Output when project started from IDE (Visual Studio):** 
Ctor
0
Finalized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you want deterministic resource cleanup you should not rely on finalizer being called, check out "When everything you know is wrong" article ([p1](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/), [p2](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/)), implement the `IDisposable` and follow the pattern.

Secondary - check out [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/76303), it seems that issue is not about finalizer per se but the object not being collected - it seems that JIT somehow prolongs lifetime of the "last" instance of the `MyClass`. For example the following will collect (on my machine =)) only the "first" object:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{    
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    NewFunction();
}

Console.WriteLine($"Collected: {MyClass.collected}");
Console.ReadKey();

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
void NewFunction()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    var gen = GC.GetGeneration(myClass);
    Console.WriteLine(gen);
    myClass = null;
    Console.WriteLine(myClass);
    Collect();
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static void Collect()
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

public class MyClass
{
    private static int counter;
    public static int collected;
    public int Id { get; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Id  = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        Console.WriteLine("Ctor");
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        collected++;
        Console.WriteLine($"Finalizer {Id}");
    }
}
```

But adding  the following between the cycle and final `Console.WriteLine`:

```cs
while (MyClass.collected != 2)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Collect();
}
```

Triggers both instances being collected and finalized.

Also check [.NET Memory Performance Analysis: Why isn't the GC collecting these objects? They should be collected!](https://github.com/Maoni0/mem-doc/blob/master/doc/.NETMemoryPerformanceAnalysis.md#faq-2)

Comment: I've tried adding [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] this didn't work but the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)] attribute did. I will proceed reading links from your comment! Thanks a lot.

Comment: btw Sonar Rules also give a comliant way of using dispose and finalizers https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-3881