# Entity Framework uses too much memory in my ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, memory-management

I have an ASP.NET Web API project and I am using some background service where i update my DB and add new data(~20000 rows) every 8 hours
But even for the first iteration of queries my app is using 400mb of memory(though in DB data it is only ~25mb)
And memory usage keeps increasing after each iteration.

I have 2 quesitions:

1.Am i doing something wrong with DbContext so it doesnt dispose correctly?

2.If not, how can i decrease memory usage in my application?

I tried to use GC.Collect() and it caused some effect, but it still consumes 660 mb after 3 calls to DB
There are photos of memory profiler( red line states for end of one iteration)

**Memory usage without GC**
[WithoutGC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gU9r.png)

**Memory usage with GC**
[WithGC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kq4E.png)

Here some code that reproduces the problem

*Program.cs*

```cs
using EFMemoryExample;
using EFMemoryExample.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
//Add database
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    //Change SQL connect string for your local db
    options.UseMySQL("server = localhost; user = root; database = test_db; password =admin;");
}
);
//Add worker
builder.Services.AddHostedService<RefreshWorker>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

*RefreshWoker.cs*

```cs
 public class RefreshWorker : BackgroundService
 {
     private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
     public RefreshWorker(IServiceProvider provider)
     {
         _provider = provider;
     }
     protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
     {
         while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
             try
             {
                 //I am doing some htpps request here but i'll generate some for test
                 var testResponseData = new List<Item>();
                 for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
                 {
                     var item = new Item()
                     {
                         Description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam",
                         Name = $"{i} Name",
                         Type = "postItem",
                     };
                     testResponseData.Add(item);
                 }
                 //All new object from http request should be added to Db
                 using var scope = _provider.CreateScope();
                 using var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                 db.Items.AddRange(testResponseData);
                 db.SaveChanges();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Console.Error.WriteLine("Error while refreshing Items: " + ex);
             }

             //It is supposed to be 8 hours but for example i left 5 sec
             await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
             //Delete comment if you want to try with GC
             //GC.Collect();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried running app in release mode?

Comment: Also since you know the collection size change your `testResponseData` initialization to `var testResponseData = new List<Item>(20_000);` which can reduce allocations a bit.

Comment: @GuruStron I think this was purely for demonstrating to show us, rather than actual data processing. I assume OP hasn't included this in the code he runs to get his data.

Comment: @Roe OP claims that the shown code reproduces the behavior (though I have not tried it yet). There are multiple possible reasons here, one is that running in debug mode can in some cases make JIT prolong the lifetime of an object - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76121746/2501279) so the memory is not reclaimed fully.

Comment: I fully agree on debug mode, I just thought that he used the HTTP request. Now that i have reread it it says for "test" not just to anonymize his code, my bad. To add on to your suggestion, you wouldn't need any list to add to. Simply add the items to the db inside the creation loop and saving after might increase performance. I'm not entirely sure what effect this will have on memory. But i would expect this could help too

Comment: Also note that list of reference types with size of 20_000 should be placed in LOH for x64  processes if I have calculated correctly, which can have some effect also (but not that noticable though).

Comment: You could create and save the data in chunks, using a new context per chunk, and execute the whole process in a `TransactionScope`. That will reduce the memory imprint of the context's change tracker.

Comment: @GuruStron I tried running it in release and it actually helped! My application started to consume stable 300mb. I think for now i am satisfied with this result. Thank you!

Comment: That's actually *not* acceptable. 22K rows is *no data* for an ETL tool. ORMs like EF Core aren't ETL tools though. You're using watchmaker's tools to hammer rocks. If you use SqlBulkCopy combined with FastMember's ObjectReader, you'll see that almost no memory is used and the import will take seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all note that running in Debug mode can heavily affect the app's captured memory footprint - see for example [this answer and links there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76121746/2501279) (especially about JIT prolonging object lifetime in the debug mode), so try running your app in Release mode.

Next point to consider is that EF Core is not very well suited for bulk inserts. Modification in EF (usually) works based on the [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/) so EF will need to preserve the local collection of entities so it can later save them. If you are running in memory-constrained environment and/or don't want memory spikes for such relatively massive inserts then you can look for some workarounds (like creating a transaction and manually chunking the batch and calling `SaveChanges` per chunk and clearing change tracker/recreating context after each chunk, or looking into some 3rd party tools like [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)).

Comment: Those "extensions" don't do what they claim. They use SqlBulkCopy to import data into a temporary table. EF itself isn't involved and the actual process is less efficient than actually creating a proper staging table, perhaps in a different filespace, with appropriate indexes and stored procedures. Or partition switching for instantaneous "upsert".