# WeakReference not Garbage Collected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, weak-references

It is my understanding that after all strong references to the `Target` of a `WeakReference` are set to null and the GC is invoked, that weak reference should no longer be alive.

However, the code below does not appear to follow this expectation:

```
    static void Main(string[] _) {
        var person = new Person();
        var wr = new WeakReference(person);

        person = null;

        // We should have access to the person here
        if (wr.Target is Person shouldExist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Person exists! IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}.");
            shouldExist = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Person does not exist :( IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}.");
        }

        // Invoke GC.Collect.            
        GC.Collect();


        if (wr.Target is Person shouldNotExist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This person should have been garbage collected");
            Console.WriteLine($"IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This person was garbage collected and weak reference is no longer alive");
            Console.WriteLine($"IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}");
        }
    }
```

where

```
class Person
{
    private int mI = 3;
    public int MI { get => mI; set => mI = value; }
}
```

And the output is

*Person exists! IsAlive: True.
This person should have been garbage collected
IsAlive: True*

I was expecting the output to be:

*Person exists! IsAlive: True.
This person was garbage collected and weak reference is no longer alive
IsAlive: False*

Am I missing something here about how weak references work?

Comment: Are you running in debug? This may affect the lifetimes of objects.

Comment: @JonasH - Nope, was running in release as was aware that may affect things.

Comment: Did you run it from visual studio? Having a debugger attached or not may also affect things.

Comment: Yes, from VS. However, in light of JIT behaviour as described in answers below and implementing as in accepted answer - all is good.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the other answers. In my experience, objects become eligible for collection after the last usage, regardless of scope of any references. This can be an issue if an object is used by native code, where `GC.KeepAlive` sometimes need to be used to extend the lifetime of objects.

Comment: But it seem to be framework dependent. Running your example in .net 4.8 without a debugger releases the object. Running it in .Net 7 keeps the object alive, regardless of debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of the references to the `Person` object in `Main()` is keeping the object alive until the end of the method.

If you change the code as follows (so that the access to the `Person` object is in a separate method), it will work as expected in C# 12/.NET 8:

```
public static class Program                                    
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var wr = getWeakReference();
        checkPersonExists(wr);
        GC.Collect();

        if (wr.Target is Person shouldNotExist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This person should have been garbage collected");
            Console.WriteLine($"IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This person was garbage collected and weak reference is no longer alive");
            Console.WriteLine($"IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}");
        }
    }

    static WeakReference getWeakReference()
    {
        var person = new Person();
        var wr     = new WeakReference(person);

        return wr;
    }

    static void checkPersonExists(WeakReference wr)
    {
        // We should have access to the person here
        if (wr.Target is Person)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Person exists! IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Person does not exist :( IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}.");
        }

    }
}

class Person
{
    private int mI = 3;
    public  int MI { get => mI; set => mI = value; }
}
```

NOTE: This behaviour is not guaranteed and may vary in different versions of C#/.NET.

Answer (score 2):

From the C# standard:

> **7.9 Automatic memory management**
>
> ...
>
> *Note: The C# compiler and the garbage collector might choose to analyze code to determine which references to an object might be used in the future. For instance, if a local variable that is in scope is  the only existing reference to an object, but that local variable is never referred to in any possible continuation of execution from the current execution point in the procedure, **the garbage collector might (but is not required to) treat the object as no longer in use**. end note*

In practice C# runtimes will keep local references until the method exits, in order to enable debugging. To properly test weak references you need to construct `Person` and its `WeakReference` in a separate method.

Comment: If the garbage collector treat the object as no longer in use, why doen't it collect the object?

Comment: @shingo it is not **required to** treat it as no longer in use. As I already explained in the answer one reason for keeping objects alive for the duration of method is: debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Can't find actual docs which will explain the behavior but this is quite delicate part of the compiler/JIT behavior in terms how long it will preserve objects/links in some cases. "Fixing" null checks and moving initialization to a separate method (i.e. removing references to the `Person` inside the `Main` method) makes the code behave as expected for me (.NET 8):

```cs
var wr = Initialize();

// We should have access to the person here
if (wr.Target is not null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Person exists! IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Person does not exist :( IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}.");
}

// Invoke GC.Collect.            
GC.Collect();


if (wr.Target is not null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This person should have been garbage collected");
    Console.WriteLine($"IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("This person was garbage collected and weak reference is no longer alive");
    Console.WriteLine($"IsAlive: {wr.IsAlive}");
}

WeakReference Initialize()
{
    var person = new Person();
    var weakReference = new WeakReference(person);

    person = null;
    return weakReference;
}
```

[Demo @ sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

**NB!**

Be sure to run this in Release mode since JIT can prolong object liftime in Debug - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76121746/2501279).